# Creating dynamic xml file using in linq to xml in C# Error "String cannot be of zero length. Parameter name: oldValue"

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Here is the screenshot of the error

[image]

[image]
[image]

I want to happen is that create an xml file dynamically, the nodes of the xml will be the `string[] textBoxNamesArray` and the value will be the `string[] textBoxTextArray`

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the call to `String.Replace`.  [The first argument cannot be an empty string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx).  And since you are replacing "" with `string.Empty` that call isn't really needed and can be removed.

So change the line to

```
xml.Add(new XElement(i, o));
```

Answer (score 2):

you are replacing empty string, the first parameter of ur `i.replace()` is `""` , its not allowed

you must mention here your old string which you want to replace

if you don't want to replace any value, then simply do like this:

```
xml.Add(new XElement(i, o));
```